# How to convert a String into an array of Strings containing one character each

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a small problem here.I need to convert a string read from console into each character of string. For example string: "aabbab" I want to this string into array of string.How would I do that?

Comment: You should select Joachim's answer as the official one if it worked for you.

Answer (score 21):

```
String[] result = input.split("(?!^)");
```

What this does is split the input String on all empty Strings that are not preceded by the beginning of the String.

Comment: When i do.

String test = "This is a test";
and then i do
String[] test2 = test.split("(?!^)");

The array only holds the characters from the first word..?

Comment: @thefiscster510: I can't reproduce this, it works just fine for me.

Comment: @JoachimSauer What does the "(?!^)" inside the parentheses mean/do?

Answer (score 17):

```
String x = "stackoverflow";
String [] y = x.split("");
```

Answer (score 5):

If by array of String you mean array of char:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String test = "aabbab ";
        char[] t = test.toCharArray();

        for(char c : t)
            System.out.println(c);    

        System.out.println("The end!");    
    }
}
```

If not, the `String.split()` function could transform a String into an array of String

See those [`String.split`](http://www.java-examples.com/java-string-split-example) examples

```
/* String to split. */
String str = "one-two-three";
String[] temp;

/* delimiter */
String delimiter = "-";
/* given string will be split by the argument delimiter provided. */
temp = str.split(delimiter);
/* print substrings */
for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++)
  System.out.println(temp[i]);
```

The `input.split("(?!^)")` proposed by [Joachim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40342/joachim-sauer) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372599/how-to-convert-a-string-into-an-array-of-strings-containing-one-character-each/1372613#1372613) is based on:

- a '`?!`' zero-width negative lookahead (see [Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))
- the caret '`^`' as an [Anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to match the start of the string the regex pattern is applied to

Any character which is not the first will be split. An empty string will not be split but return an empty array.

Comment: thats an array of chars, not an array of strings

Comment: @Chii: true, I have illustrated both results now. `char[]` and `String[]`

Answer (score 2):

You mean you want to do "aabbab".toCharArray(); ?  Which will return an array of chars.  Or do you actually want the resulting array to contain single character string objects?

Answer (score 1):

You can use String.split(String regex):

```
String input = "aabbab";
String[] parts = input.split("(?!^)");
```

Comment: Since each character is a separator no character will be data, so you'll get an empty array.

Comment: Thanks don't know that it can be used with split but why it's splited with ?!^ ? cos a string doesn't have that in there?

Comment: @unknown: it's a regular expression that means "an empty string not preceded by the beginning of the string". So it matches on each space between characters and splits on that.

Answer (score 1):

Use toCharArray() method. It splits the string into an array of characters:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29

```
String str = "aabbab";
char[] chs = str.toCharArray();
```