# How to convert String to String Array

Tags: java, string

hi all i have gone through many thread and i found the way but don't know how to fit in my string please give me `regex`pattern to solve this.

```
input: String [200,350,500]
output: String{"200","350","500"}
```

one of the article where i found something:

[How to convert a String into an array of Strings containing one character each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372599/how-to-convert-a-string-into-an-array-of-strings-containing-one-character-each)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the substring between the first and the last character and then split by `,`:

```
String input = "[200,350,500]";
String[] split = input.substring(1, input.length() - 1).split(",");
```

Comment: "[" bracket is also there

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "[200,350,500]";
String[] split = input.replaceAll("^.(.*).$","$1").split(",");
```

Comment: Could you also elaborate why this answer would work and what it exactly does?

Comment: It's make string array from the input string. Didn't it? replaseall - like sunstring but you shouldn't get string length and find last position of string

Comment: I know this, you know this, but it's valuable for the OP to know *how* it works as well.

Comment: I think this example in the context of the previous answer needed no comments